# selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to create new service: OperaDriverService

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, opera

OS: Ubuntu

I am following [step 2.5 of this tutorial](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#using-selenium-with-remote-webdriver):

1) I downloaded selenium server standalone of two versions:`selenium-server-standalone-2.50.1.jar` and `selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar`.

2) I created a file named test_selenium_server.py:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

driver = webdriver.Remote(
   command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
   desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)

driver = webdriver.Remote(
   command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
   desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.OPERA)

driver = webdriver.Remote(
   command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
   desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNITWITHJS)
```

I installed chromedriver and geckodriver.

When I run `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.50.1.jar` and then `python test_selenium_server.py`, I get an error like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_selenium_server.py", line 12, in <module>
    desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.OPERA)
...
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: The best matching driver provider org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver can't create a new driver instance for Capabilities [{browserName=opera, version=, platform=ANY}]
Build info: version: '2.50.1', revision: 'd7fc91b', time: '2016-01-29 19:08:26'
System info: host: 'AMDC2763', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-30-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
...
```

And when I run `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar` and then `python test_selenium_server.py`, I get an error like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_selenium_server.py", line 12, in <module>
    desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.OPERA)
...
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to create new service: OperaDriverService
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:32:19.891Z'
System info: host: 'AMDC2763', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-30-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
...
```

I've tried both python2 and python3 (they give the same errors) and searched through half the Internet, but found nothing. I believe that there is one problem that is causing those errors, that is why I showed both of error messages here. Help please.

**EDIT:** On MacOS High Sierra, I am getting the same errors.

Comment: Why are you using remote when you are testing on your local machine ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @HamzaTorjmen, I am just following the tutorial and wondering why it is not working.

Comment: @DebanjanB, I am afraid I find my question limited enough.

Comment: @ibodi 2 selenium versions `2.50.1` and `3.13.0`; 2 Python versions `python2` and `python3`; still have to say _limited enough_?

Comment: @DebanjanB, I just gave I little bit more information that may be necessary. I am convinced, however, that the solution which would make those errors disappear is one, therefore, there should be one question, on my opinion.

Comment: @ibodi do you have a server that is running selenium with ip 127.0.0.1 on your machine ? because normally 127.0.0.1 for servers on local machine so you don't need to use webdriver.remote

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace tells me you haven't got Opera registered to your (remote) local selenium server.

The tutorial you mention gives 3 *different* **examples** to start *different* type of sessions.

That tutorial does not seem to mention how to tell your server you have opera (and potentially irrelevant to selenium-python, as its generic to selenium and hasn't got to do with client python bindings). 
If you need to test several browser, I'd recommend starting your server as a Selenium Grid, described [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2). You could register an Opera node to it.